# Allocating different channels to multi-radio interfaces of a wireless node

Tags: omnet++

There are several frequency bands within the radio spectrum that are used for the Wi-Fi and within these, there are many channels that have been designated with numbers so they can be identified.
The table given below provides the frequencies for the total of fourteen 802.11 Wi-Fi channels that are available around the globe.
[image: 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi channels, frequencies, etc, showing overlap and which ones can be used as sets]

How to allocate different channels for example 1, 3, 8 to three-radio interfaces of a wireless node as drawn in Figure 2 for node 1?
The Showcases > Wireless > Multiple Wireless Interfaces example is not my answer. (without access point and set channel number to the interface not based on SSID for tuning channel for periods of simulation time is intended. See the second figure)
[image: Figure 2-A multi-radio Ad-hoc wireless network]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set in `omnetpp.ini`:

```
*.host[*].wlan[*].radio.bandwidth = 20MHz
*.host[0].wlan[0].radio.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz  # channel no 1
*.host[0].wlan[1].radio.centerFrequency = 2.422GHz  # channel no 3
*.host[0].wlan[2].radio.centerFrequency = 2.447GHz  # channel no 8
# and so on ...
```

Reference: [Ieee80211Radio](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211Radio.html).

Comment: Thanks to @Jerzy D. Can I draw conclusions from your answer:  

1) Is wlan equivalent to radio-interface? Because you used wlan[0], wlan[1], and wlan[2] for three interfaces of host[0].  

2) Why you don't use channelNumber parameter instead of centerFrequency parameter? For example, instead of expression "*.host[0].wlan[1].radio.centerFrequency = 2.422GHz  # channel no 3" can I use the expression "*.host[0].wlan[1].radio.channelNumber = 2  # channel no 3"

Comment: Ad. 1) Yes. Ad. 2) Because I have never used channelNumber. But you can check its implementation and try to use.

Comment: @JerzyD. Indeed, it is recommended to use the channelNumber parameter. `centerFequency` is automatically calculated from that, so that is used only if you want to override that for some obscure reason. @reza you should take a look at `examples/wireless/multiradio` example because that one does exactly what you want to achieve. And do not forget to accept an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks to @Rudi, I usually accept answers one or two days late so as not to diminish the motivation of others to participate in the inquiry. Dear Jerzy and Rudi are the best persons for answering in Omnet++ discussions.